# Trouble with resx file, while deploying site on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

So i am trying to deploy my web asp.net mvc website on IIS. It works perfectly on my pc etc, but after deployment i am getting this error:

> Compilation Error 
>     Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Resources' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Source Error:

```
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" class="exit">@Resources.Localization.exit</a>
```

My build action property on `Resources.Localization` is set to `Embedded Resource`

I have found a tip here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1442744.aspx?Problem+deploying+MVC+app+on+IIS7

And changed it value to `Content` another error appears:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "BTGHRM.App_GlobalResources.Localization.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "BTGHRM" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "BTGHRM.App_GlobalResources.Localization.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "BTGHRM" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Error Source:

```
Line 40:                                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { style = "color:#0D5C9F;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;" })
```

[image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copied (cntrl-c cntrl-v) a resource file to the server and it worked. Just wtf.